# Метод Console.Read возвращает неверное значение числа

Tags: c#

сделал маленькую игру по угадыванию чисел но загвоздка в том то что рандом выдает большие числа чем прописаны в условий [image: #]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sLVA.png)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в вопрос делайте текстом, а не картинкой пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код текстом вместо картинок.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно документации метод [Consol.Read()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8) возвращает

> "следующий символ из входного потока или значение минус единица (-1),
>   если доступных для чтения символов не осталось."

При чем эта функция возвращает не сам символ, а его код (тип возвращаемого значение - `int`)

В вашем случае вы ввели символ `1` с кодом 49 по стандарту [ASCII](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), с которым совместима кодировка UTF-16, используемая по умолчанию в .NET. Потому переменная y вас равна 49.

**Как решить?**

Вместо `Console.Read()` используйте `Console.Readline()` и метод `int.Parse` либо [int.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) для получения валидного числа, например, так:

```
int y;
var str = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse(str, out y)) return;
```